# How to use TextWatcher in android?

Tags: android

I have a custom ListView which contains one TextView (Of numbers) and one EditText in a row. Outside the heading I have a TextView.

My Questing is that, when I am going to enter any number into any editText then on **heading textView** it should display the **multiplication of editText Value * textView Value of row of ListView.**

And after that if i enter any other number inside any other editText then the calculation will be same like previous one, say **multiplication of editText Value * textView Value of row of ListView + multiplication of editText Value * textView Value of row of ListView** and display this **new value on the heading textView**. And if change the value any editText then the previous value of **old position should be updated** on new value of **corrosponding position.** 
I know all this work is going to be happened in the textwatcher but don't know how??
Can you help me???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this piece of code will help you.....

```
EditText etSearchBar = (EditText)findViewById(Your_id);

    etSearchBar.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);

    private TextWatcher textwatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                //Do what ever you want here after you enter each text
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

in getView method of Adapter, setTextChangeListener over editText, and in TextWatcher onTextChanged method, do calculations, and setText to textView at top.